# Counting by analizing two column in difficult pattern in awk by using probably arrays

Tags: arrays, awk, text-processing

I have a huge problem. I try to create a script, which counts a specific sum (sum of water bridges never mind). This is a small part of my data file

```
POP62 SOL11
KAR1  SOL24
KAR5  SOL31
POP17 SOL42
POP15 SOL2
POP17 SOL2
KAR7  SOL42
KAR1  SOL11
KAR6  SOL31
```

In the first column, I have POP or KAR with numbers like KAR1, POP17, etc. In the second column, I have always SOL with a number, but I have max 2 the same SOL (for example, I can have maximum 2 SOL42 or SOL11 etc., KAR and POP I can have more than 2).

And now the thing that I want to do.
If I find that the same SOL is connected with **both** KAR and POP (whatever number) I add 1. For example:

```
KAR6  SOL5
POP8  SOL5
```

I add one to sum

In my data

```
POP62 SOL11
KAR1  SOL24
KAR5  SOL31
POP17 SOL42
POP15 SOL2
POP17 SOL2
KAR7  SOL42
KAR1  SOL11
KAR6  SOL31
```

I should have sum = 2
,because

```
POP17 SOL42
KAR7  SOL42
```

and

```
POP62 SOL11
KAR1  SOL11
```

Do you have any idea how to do that. I think about using NR=FNR and going through the file two times and check the repetitions in the $2 maybe by using an array, but what next?

```
#!/bin/bash 
awk 'NR==FNR         ?? 
       some condition {sum++}  
       END             {print sum}' test1.txt{,} >> water_bridges_x2.txt
```

Edit solution
I also add 0 if it is empty, because I want print 0 instead of null

```
awk '
{
   s = $1
   sub(/[0-9]+$/, "", s)           # strip digits from end in var s
   if ($2 in map && map[$2] != s)  # if existing entry is not same 
      ++sum                        # increment sum
   map[$2] = s
}
END {print sum+0}' file

2
```

Comment: Make SOLxy to be a *key* in an associative array (dictionary) and an array of corresponding KARs and POPs to be a *value* in the dictionary. When the whole set of data is put into the dictionary, iterate through the keys in the dictionary and check how many elements are in the value array. Add 1 to the result if the value array has required elements (that is at least one KAR and one POP)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this `awk`:

```sh
awk '
{
   s = $1
   sub(/[0-9]+$/, "", s)           # strip digits from end in var s
   if ($2 in map && map[$2] != s)  # if existing entry is not same 
      ++sum                        # increment sum
   map[$2] = s
}
END {print sum+0}' file

2
```

Comment: Thanks, stripping digits was a good idea! Thank you so much, Fantastic script and thanks also for the comments on this script.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, here is another way of doing it. Written and tested in GNU `awk`, should work in any `awk`.

```
awk '
{
  match($1,/^[a-zA-Z]+/)
  val=substr($1,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  if(($2 in arr) && arr[$2]!=val){
    sum++
  }
  arr[$2]=val
}
END{
  print sum
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

A similar answer to @anubhava's: this uses GNU awk for the multi-dimensional array:

```sh
gawk '
    {sols[$2][substr($1,0,3)] = 1} 
    END {
        for (sol in sols) 
            if ("POP" in sols[sol] && "KAR" in sols[sol]) 
                sum++
        print sum
    }
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

another solution

```
$ sed -E 's/[0-9]+ +/ /' file    |   # cleanup data
  sort -k2                       |   # sort by key
  uniq                           |   # remove dups
  uniq -c -f1                    |   # count by key
  egrep '^ +2 ' -c                   # report the sum where count is 2.

2
```